# Is there a way to assign pod-network-cidr in kubeadm after initialization?

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm, flannel

I used `kubeadm` to initialize my K8 master. However, I missed the `--pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16` flag to be used with flannel. Is there a way (or a config file) I can modify to reflect this subnet without carrying out the re-init process again?

Comment: Edit the generated CNI config files?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Override PodCIDR parameter on the all k8s Node resource with a IP source range `10.244.0.0/16`

```
$ kubectl edit nodes nodename
```

Replace "Network" field under net-conf.json header in the relevant Flannel ConfigMap with a new network IP range:

```
$ kubectl edit cm kube-flannel-cfg -n kube-system
net-conf.json: | { "Network": "10.244.0.0/16", "Backend": { "Type": "vxlan" } }
```

Wipe current CNI network interfaces remaining the old network pool:

```
$ sudo ip link del cni0; sudo ip link del flannel.1
```

Re-spawn Flannel and CoreDNS pods respectively:

```
$ kubectl delete pod --selector=app=flannel -n kube-system
$ kubectl delete pod --selector=k8s-app=kube-dns -n kube-system
```

Wait until CoreDNS pods obtain IP address from a new network pool. Keep in mind that your custom Pods will still retain the old IP addresses inside containers unless you re-create them manually as well

Comment: Attempting to override the `podCIDR` parameter results in the error:
`# nodes "(the  node name)" was not valid:
# * spec.podCIDRs: Forbidden: node updates may not change podCIDR except from "" to valid
`

Comment: Great answer. Thank you. In my case, replacing the "Network" field was not necessary. It was already set correctly.

Comment: The Network section isn't available in Kubernetes 1.21.8, when I run `kubectl edit nodes`.

Comment: This will result in duplicate IP addresses. podCIDR should be unique for each node or not set at all. More over, if you use this approach of setting podCIDR you have to do this for every new node manually.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the first point. I cannot see the PodCIDR parameter anywhere in the file. TBH I'm happy to re-init with kubeadm but cannot find docs on how to specify --pod-network-cidr on the config file.